# For the lab "Deploy Application to Azure Kubernetes Service" why does the site not load?

Tags: azure-aks, azure-deployment

has anyone did this lately?
https://microsoft.github.io/PartsUnlimited/iac/200.2x-IaCDeployApptoAKS.html

I followed it to the letter and the website would not load

```
This site can’t be reached
<LoadBalancer External-IP> took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
```

What I have noticed as a difference I got

```
  "servicePrincipalProfile": {
    "clientId": "msi",
    "secret": null
```

and their screenshot showed a GUID for clientId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tested in my environment working fine for me you need to change image name for `azure-vote-front` from        `image: microsoft/azure-vote-front:v1` to `image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1`.**

```
containers:
- name: azure-vote-front
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1
```

Same is Stated in this [**Microsoft Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-application?tabs=azure-cli).as well.

**OutPut -**--

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you that was it.
I would have not thought all steps  on https://microsoft.github.io/ were not accurate - in fact only the link to the image repository was not correct - was following them religiously so not to miss anything.

Comment: Also, is there a way I could have noticed this myself, that no image was retrieved?

Comment: Found it, all the time it was there under 'Current workloads' but if you don't know where to look :(


azure-vote-front
Waiting
ImagePullBackOff
False
0
microsoft/azure-vote-front:v1

Comment: Glad that it helped you.